# How to write multiple Selenium WebDriver session logs into different files when they run parallel using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

Looking for a solution to write **step by step** execution details of Selenium webDriver scripts into a file. Logs need to be added to files which are created for each 'Tests' in **testng.xml** and are running on the different browser.
That has been achieved for 'one session' by implementing **WebDriverEventListener**.(But I don't have an idea of writing each driver instance custom logs into different files within a single method)
But looking for a solution to bind each 'log files' with 'Webdriver instances' and write respective browser actions into it.

```
@Parameters({"BrowserName"})    
@BeforeTest
public void createDriver(String BrowserName) {
    switch (BrowserName) {
    case "Chrome":
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//BrowserExes//chromedriver.exe");
        Driver = new ChromeDriver();
        eventFiringDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(Driver);
        eventListener = new CustomWebDriverListener(Driver);
        eventFiringDriver.register(eventListener);
        break;

    case "IE":
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//BrowserExes//IEDriverServer.exe");
        Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        eventFiringDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(Driver);
        eventListener = new CustomWebDriverListener(Driver);
        eventFiringDriver.register(eventListener);

    default:
        break;
    }

}


@Test
public void loadURL(){
  eventFiringDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

I have created report files by implementing **ISuiteListener** based on the number of TestNG tests.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
<test name="Test">
    <parameter name="BrowserName" value="Chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="eventFiringWebDriver.EventDriver"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test_2">
    <parameter name="BrowserName" value="IE"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="eventFiringWebDriver.EventDriver"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this very easily if you rely on a logging framework such as SLF4j.
On a highlevel you need to leverage a `SiftingAppender` that SLF4j provides you and inject values to the variables that you refer to in your `logback.xml` from your code.

I have captured all of this information in [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/testcase-specific-logs-for-a-selenium-project/) blog post of mine with a sample as well.

But for the sake of reference I am including the bare essentials here in this post as well.

Here's how my `logback.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>fileName</key>
            <defaultValue>defaultTest</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${fileName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>${fileName}.log</file>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{20} | %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Here's a modified listener for injecting into `EventFiringWebDriver`

```
public class LogAwareWebDriverEventListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener{

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("Loading url " + url);
    }

    public void bindLogName(String log, String folderName) {
        String path = new File(folderName).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
        MDC.put("fileName", path + log);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        MDC.remove("fileName");
    }
}
```

Here's how a test case looks like which uses all of this.

```
public class ManyTestCases {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        runTest("http://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        runTest("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }

    private void runTest(String url) {
        ChromeDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();
        EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(cd);
        LogAwareWebDriverEventListener listener = new LogAwareWebDriverEventListener();
        String outputFolder = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getSuite().getOutputDirectory();
        listener.bindLogName(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getName(), outputFolder);
        driver.register(listener);
        driver.get(url);
        driver.quit();
        listener.unbind();
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

References :

- https://dzone.com/articles/adding-slf4j-your-maven
- https://dzone.com/articles/siftingappender-logging
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545048/679824 (Referred this to figure out how to work with multiple discriminators in SLF4j )

Comment: I understood you have created multiple log files for **@tests**, not for multiple **WebDriver** instances. If am wrong, would you like to drop some light on achieving this? I need log/write step details into different files, which is created based on a number of "WebDriver" instances created from 'suite.xml'. in this context, I am using two browsers 'Chrome and IE' and I have only one test Method.

Comment: From this test method, I need to write execution details according to each driver instance (passing only Driver). Eg: Maybe one step success in 'IE' but the same may fail in 'Chrome'. But my files log these details individually by listening each driver.

Comment: @Ajesh - If you look carefully at the example that I shared, you would notice that it is indeed on a per webdriver instance basis (i create a webdriver instance in every test method). You should be able to extend this same approach and do it in whatever way you need. The sample that I showed you should be easy to adopt for you to solve your specific need.

Comment: I tried to run the code by referring "slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar". But it didn't create a log file, instead  exception thrown in console
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Can you guide me?

Comment: Also using 'logback-classic' gives error on **LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("Loading url " + url);**.
Could you please tell me where I am wrong. I am running a java project not a maven one.

Comment: @Ajesh : You should be able to resolve things by going through this tutorial : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html .

Comment: Thanks, Krishnan, that's worked. I have modified the same for different driver sessions.